# how to iterate through xml data to remove next duplicate element using lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am struggling to come up with a simple solution which iterates over xml data to remove the next element if it is a dplicate of the actual one.

**example:**

from this "input":

```
<root>
    <b attrib1="abc" attrib2="def">
        <c>data1</c>
    </b>
    <b attrib1="abc" attrib2="def">
        <c>data2</c>
    </b>
    <b attrib1="uvw" attrib2="xyz">
        <c>data3</c>
    </b>
    <b attrib1="abc" attrib2="def">
        <c>data4</c>
    </b>
    <b attrib1="abc" attrib2="def">
        <c>data5</c>
    </b>
    <b attrib1="abc" attrib2="def">
        <c>data6</c>
    </b>
</root>
```

I would like to get to this "output":

```
<root>
    <b attrib1="abc" attrib2="def">
        <c>data1</c>
    </b>
    <b attrib1="uvw" attrib2="xyz">
        <c>data3</c>
    </b>
    <b attrib1="abc" attrib2="def">
        <c>data4</c>
    </b>
</root>'''
```

for doing this I came up with the following code:

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO


xml = '''
<root>
    <b attrib1="abc" attrib2="def">
        <c>data1</c>
    </b>
    <b attrib1="abc" attrib2="def">
        <c>data2</c>
    </b>
    <b attrib1="uvw" attrib2="xyz">
        <c>data3</c>
    </b>
    <b attrib1="abc" attrib2="def">
        <c>data4</c>
    </b>
    <b attrib1="abc" attrib2="def">
        <c>data5</c>
    </b>
    <b attrib1="abc" attrib2="def">
        <c>data6</c>
    </b>
</root>'''

# this is to simulate that above xml was read from a file
file = StringIO(unicode(xml))

# reading the xml from a file
tree = etree.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()

# iterate over all "b" elements
for element in root.iter('b'):
    # checks if the last "b" element has been reached.
    # on last element it raises "AttributeError" eception and terminates the for loop
    try:
        # attributes of actual element
        elem_attrib_ACT = element.attrib
        # attributes of next element
        elem_attrib_NEXT = element.getnext().attrib
    except AttributeError:
        # if no other element, break
        break
    print('attributes of ACTUAL elem:', elem_attrib_ACT, 'attributes of NEXT elem:', elem_attrib_NEXT)
    if elem_attrib_ACT == elem_attrib_NEXT:
        print('next elem is duplicate of actual one -> remove it')
        # I would like to remove next element but this approach is not working
        # if you uncomment, it removes the elements of "data2" but stops
        # how to remove the next duplicate element?
        #element.getparent().remove(element.getnext())
    else:
        print('next elem is not a duplicate of actual')

print('result:')
print(etree.tostring(root))
```

uncommenting line

```
#element.getparent().remove(element.getnext())
```

removes the elements around "data2" but stops execution. the resulting xml is this one:

```
<root>
    <b attrib1="abc" attrib2="def">
        <c>data1</c>
    </b>
    <b attrib1="uvw" attrib2="xyz">
        <c>data3</c>
    </b>
    <b attrib1="abc" attrib2="def">
        <c>data4</c>
    </b>
    <b attrib1="abc" attrib2="def">
        <c>data5</c>
    </b>
    <b attrib1="abc" attrib2="def">
        <c>data6</c>
    </b>
</root>
```

my impression is that i "cut the branch on which I am sitting"...

any suggestions how to solve this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your suspicion is correct, if you put a print statement before you break in the `except` block you can see it's breaking early because this element has been removed (I think)

```
<b attrib1="abc" attrib2="def">
    <c>data2</c>
</b>
```

Try using `getprevious()` instead of `getnext()`. I also updated to use list comprehension to avoid the error on the first element (which of course will raise an exception at the `.getprevious()`):

```
for element in [e for e in root.iter('b')][1:]:
    try:
        if element.getprevious().attrib == element.attrib:
            element.getparent().remove(element)
    except:
        print 'except  '
print etree.tostring(root)
```

results:

```
<root>
<b attrib1="abc" attrib2="def">
    <c>data1</c>
</b>
<b attrib1="uvw" attrib2="xyz">
    <c>data3</c>
</b>
<b attrib1="abc" attrib2="def">
    <c>data4</c>
</b>
</root>
```

Comment: @udo no problem! I made a slight revision to avoid the attribute error by using list comprehension in the `for` loop.

Comment: is removing an element during the iteration safe? does it invalidate iterators?

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik it is generally advisable to iterate backwards if you plan on removing items from a collection.